# Create a boolean array A from two 1-D vectors a, b, and A[i,j] is True if a[i]==b[j]

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

Given two numpy vectors `a` and `b`, I want to create a 2D array `A` and `A[i,j]=True` if `a[i]==b[j]`. I can do the following for-loop. But I wonder if I can do it without for-loop to get the result faster.

```
def f(x, y):
    d = np.zeros((len(x),len(y)))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        d[i, np.argwhere(y==x[i])]=1
    return d
a = np.array([1,2,3,1,3,4])
b = np.array([1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5])
```

And `f(a,b)` is:

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [296]: a = np.array([1,2,3,1,3,4]) 
     ...: b = np.array([1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5])                                       
In [297]: a[:,None]==b                                                          
Out[297]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False]])
In [298]: _.astype(int)                                                         
Out[298]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

or with `where`:

```
In [301]: d=np.zeros((len(a),len(b)),int)                                       
In [302]: np.where(a[:,None]==b)                                                
Out[302]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 5, 6]))
In [303]: d[_]=1                                                                
In [304]: d                                                                     
Out[304]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want.